# Не выводит массив (PHP)

Tags: php

Приветствую.

```
    var_dump($data);
echo "Имя: ".$data["name"];
```

Не выводит имя, хотя вар_дамп показывает:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["name"]=> string(9) "admin" ["email"]=> string(14) "none@gmail.com" } }
```

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам надо обратиться к элементу по другому:

```
echo "Имя: ".$data[0]["name"];
```

P.S.: у вас должен был вывестись нотис: `"Notice: Undefined index"`, возможно его нет из-за настроек PHP.

Comment: @ua6xh, спасибо! Ошибся, сделал, случайно, двумерный массив.